# Undefined symbols for arm64 when building with `swift build`

Tags: swift, terminal, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I've made a command-line application in Swift that until recently ran just fine. I believe it was after upgrading to macOS 14.4, however, that it stopped working properly. I can still build the application in Xcode with ⌘B, but building it from terminal with `swift build -c debug` (or `release`) produces an error message stating that linking failed:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "(extension in pmax):Swift.String.includeCommentsInAssembly.unsafeMutableAddressor : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      pmax.Build.run() throws -> () in Build.swift.o
      pmax.AssemblyLowerer.(lowerAsExecutable in _B842627F49AC85AC0E595B2E225F391B)(inout Swift.String) -> () in _AssemblyLowerer.swift.o
      pmax.TACStatement.lowerToBreadboardAssembly() -> Swift.String in _asm_tac.swift.o
  "(extension in pmax):Swift.String.build(Swift.String, Swift.String?) -> Swift.String", referenced from:
      pmax.TACStatement.lowerToBreadboardAssembly() -> Swift.String in _asm_tac.swift.o
      (extension in pmax):Swift.String.ldraw(Swift.Int, Swift.Int, Swift.String?) -> Swift.String in instructions.swift.o
      (extension in pmax):Swift.String.li(Swift.Int, Swift.Int, Swift.String?) -> Swift.String in instructions.swift.o
      (extension in pmax):Swift.String.lidata(Swift.Int, Swift.Int, Swift.String?) -> Swift.String in instructions.swift.o
      (extension in pmax):Swift.String.mv(Swift.Int, Swift.Int, Swift.String?) -> Swift.String in instructions.swift.o
      (extension in pmax):Swift.String.mv(Swift.Int, Swift.Int, Swift.String?) -> Swift.String in instructions.swift.o
      (extension in pmax):Swift.String.addi(Swift.Int, Swift.Int, Swift.Int, Swift.String?) -> Swift.String in instructions.swift.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: fatalError
```

I've tried cleaning the build folder (`rm -rf .build`) and updating packages (`swift package update`). What's interesting is that other Swift applications can still be built from the terminal, indicating that this is an issue with my application, and not with the Swift compiler or toolchain. I realize that it may be difficult to point to exactly where things go wrong, but if this seems familiar or anyone has an idea, input is greatly appreciated.